# Replace BJT with a MOSFET for a mini 24 V motor

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor

I have a mini 24 VDC motor (RH-370CC) with the following specs:

[image: ![RH-370CC specs]

It is controlled by an ESP32 (3.3 V output). My initial design was the following:

[image: circuit diagram]

I know, I made a poor choice with the SS8050 transistor.
It worked well in the early tests but it lasted a few seconds when the motor didn't have any load.

Is there any MOSFET in a TO-92 package that I can use to replace the SS8050 transistor?
Unfortunately I already made the PCB.

Comment: Yes. There are. The MOSFET current should be 1A.

Comment: Are you using PWM to vary the speed of the motor, or is it just on/off?

Comment: For now it's just ON/OFF but I'm thinking to control the motor in PWM (by using the ESP32 analog output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a solution to your problem: You're not driving the transistor hard enough. With 470 Ohms, you'll get about 5mA of base current with 3.3V from the ESP32's GPIO. Ideally, the base current should be at least 1/10th of the collector current. Your motor might need 200mA or so to actually spin up, so you'd aim for 20mA base current.

This means that it'll likely work fine if you decrease the base resistor to 100 Ohms. The ESP32 can handle this, too.

You might also want to consider using a higher voltage transistor, i.e. a BC337. The SS8050's collector-emitter breakdown voltage is uncomfortably close to your 24V supply rail.

If you want to use this circuit for PWM, you should also remove C2 and drastically lower the value of C3 (to i.e. 10nF). They will otherwise cause excessive power dissipation in the transistor.

Regarding a suitable MOSFET: I checked Digi-Key, and they do not currently have any MOSFET in stock that would work for your application. The big problem is that you only have 3.3V available to drive the FET, which means that you're looking for a high current logic-level FET in TO-92. Those are rare and very hard to obtain because it's all SMD now. A BJT is the better choice here.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your response. Much appreciated.
I will definitely check the BC337 solution. 
For my knowledge, can you please tell me why the C2-C3 will have an impact on the power dissipation (in PWM)?
Also, I was googling for a Mosfet replacement. Do you think a BS170 could be an alternative?
Thanks again

Comment: @Avok78 All of the energy stored in C2 and C3 gets dumped into the transistor every time it switches on. If you switch it frequently enough (i.e. when doing PWM), the transistor will get *very* hot and might overheat. At 10kHz PWM frequency and 24V, it's already 0.5W. The BS170 will not work. It's only specified to fully turn on at 10V on the gate, and in fact, it may not turn on *at all* with only 3V to drive it. For now, you can just change the base resistor to 100 Ohms and it'll work with the SS8050.